# 'load' function unable to load mat file in a specified variable

Tags: matlab

I wanted to load a file 'data_MC_temp.mat' into a variable 'data_MC'. I tried using following command:
load('data_MC_temp.mat', 'data_MC');

But, MATLAB neither loads file into 'data_MC' variable nor gives any error or warning. Is there anything wrong with the syntax? Please help me and suggest proper way of doing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To load a file into a variable do like this:

```
data_MC = load('data_MC_temp.mat');
```

The syntax you used is only used if there is a variable insde the file `data_MC_temp.mat` called `data_MC` and you only want to load that specific variable.

Comment: It is worth to mention that the `data_MC` variable is a structure that will hold all the variables in the saved workspace (mat file).